# fread in php only read 255 characters

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fread

We are trying to read our website as a file in php and the fread function only can read 255 chars , can anyone help us in this problem?

Code:

```
$filename = "oururl";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Also when we are trying to read file through file_get_content the same result is appeared to us for only 255 chars.

Comment: What does `filesize($filename)` return?

Comment: @apokryfos 4300 byte

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a size of a remote source/file specified by URL. 
`filesize` function is able to get size of file if [**URL wrapper**](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) supports/provides [**file statistics**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php)
In your case, `http` or `https` could be used for URL wrapper.

```
$filename = "http://www.someurl.com";
```

But *Stateless* HTTP/HTTPS protocols don't provide file statistics.